# The role of the lagged dependent variable as a predictor

Tags: regression, time-series, lags

I am familiar with the distributed lags and the issues in estimating the regression model with the lagged dependent variable as one of the predictor in the equation.

Besides those issues, now and then I am tempted to use it to capture the trends and other explanatory variables I could not obtain, in addition to the usual goal of estimating the dynamic effect of a predictor.

I would like to hear from others about how stupid this idea is, so that I can avoid any mistakes in the future :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which specific "stupid idea" are you referring to?

Comment: I meant using the lagged dependent variable to capture the trend and other important predictors I possibly missed since they are not available to me. I used the word, "stupid", just in case it really is :) Thank you for your clarification question. I hope I answered your question, and people including you now can understand my question more clearly. Looking forward to eveybody's inputs!! Thanks!